# Posix named lock inter process what work with multi-thread application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, ipc

I need to create named lock that work correctly with multi-thread application for Linux. Each instance of application could use more than one named-lock with different names.

I know about `fcntl`/`flock`, but it doesn't work if try to lock twice from different thread of one application or from one thread.

I know about `open(..., O_CREATE | O_EXCL)`, but this file-lock will not be removed if application was killed by signal KILL or was crashed with segmentation fault and there is needed manual removing of lock-files after restart application.

Any another ways?

Comment: Can you please share some more information? Some code snapshot of  how  you implemented the lock?

Comment: Commonly, I need to implement function `int lock(const char *name);` and `int unlock(const char *name)` that works for correctly with multi-thread application and different instance of application.
If any thread or instance application ask `lock` twice, than second call should be failed until resource will not be unlocked with call `unlock`.
And if application was crashed, than OS should provide behaviour like function `unlock` was called.

Comment: One method to handle this is to capture the signal like segmentation, KILL and release all the locks and exit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling

Comment: Yes, most count of signal could be catched by special handler, but SIG_KILL is not allowed to do, for example. And I need to way to unlock resource in this case. I'll be happy if OS do it for me when kill application

Comment: check if this help http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to run under modern Linux, you could use [file-private locks](https://lwn.net/Articles/586904/).  If that's not an option, you'll have to build your own thread-safe locking abstraction on top of `fcntl` locks.  SQLite is public domain and has implemented that, so you could look at that for inspiration.  If GPLed code is okay: OpenJDK has another, incompatible implementation of the same thing.

`O_EXCL` does not perform locking (beyond the file creation step), so that's usually not helpful.

Other options are System V and POSIX semaphores, but these usually do not work as well as `fcntl` locks when processes day.  A robust, process-shared mutex in a file mapping could be an option as well, but you need to be careful to stay within the POSIX semantics as far as serialization to disk is concerned (basically, you need to reinitialize the mutex every time the application starts from scratch, after a reboot or libc update).